# UIDocumentInteractionController app icon NOT rounded

Tags: ios

The app icon show in the list not rounded as screenshot with strange icon, as I mark in red:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cd47cgwr0ahcx98/not_rounded.PNG?dl=0

- the apps I need include: instagram, twitter, line, whatsapp, kind social media apps,

Please help me review my code below,
Hope can fix the icon show with normal rounded,
Will be appreicated to teach or guide me if possible,
thanks.

```
NSString *documentDirectory=[FileIOUtility openDocPath:@"Temp"];
NSString *saveImagePath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.ig"];
NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(shareImage);
NSString *saveImagePathNormal=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];
[imageData writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];
[imageData writeToFile:saveImagePathNormal atomically:YES];

NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveImagePath];

docController=[[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc]init];
docController.delegate=self;

[docController setURL:imageURL];
[docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:true];
```

Comment: Do you know the [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html)? It could be the solution if you want to "export" the image to an other app.

Comment: you mean "UIDocumentInteractionController" must only can show with strange shape icon as screenshot as I post ?  https://www.dropbox.com/s/cd47cgwr0ahcx98/not_rounded.PNG?dl=0

Comment: I mean you might use `UIDocumentInteractionController` wrong, since you have an other goal anyway and `UIActivityViewController` might suit your needs better.

Comment: I think you're trying to share your image in Instagram? If so, you should use, `UIDocumentInteractionController ` and not `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: yap, I do need instagram and other social media channel to share,